# Regex rpg functions

Tags: java, regex

(Hoping to write a good question).

I have to match a RPG function in Java, using regular expressions.
The functions I have are in these possible ways:

```
nameFunction()
nameFunction(params)
nameFunction('otherFunction(' + variable + ')')
nameFunction('otherFunction.get('''+trim(string_variable)+''')')
fun1() + fun2()
```

Where the ' is used to open/close string, and ' is used also as escape char for ' itself.
I've already tried with this regex:

```
 \w+\([^\)]*\)
```

Where with \w+ I want to match the name, then the (, all chars but no the close parenthesis  and finally the closed one.
The first two functions are correctly recognized, but the third and fourth ones no. Regex matchs

```
nameFunction('otherFunction(' + variable + ')
nameFunction('otherFunction.get('''+trim(string_variable)
```

skipping the last closed parenthesis in the third and the string concatenation in the fourth (the fifth example is to show that I can have multiple functions and I want to recognize them separately).
Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "rpg function" but the RPG tag is for the programming language and is not appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

If the strings have no escapes you could use:

```
\w+\((?:[^'()]|'[^']*')*\)
```

If you want to handle backslash escapes you could do that with:

```
\w+\((?:[^'()]|'(?:[^'\\]|\\.)*')*\)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The escape for the string are the ' char itself, so I could have something like nameFunction('otherFunction.get('''+string_variable+''')') that actually does not match with your regex. It matches only get('''+%TRIM(VAR2)+''')

Comment: @farerobe That answer works well on your examples. If that's not what you're looking for, please adjust your example exactly the way they look. Not using additional symbols for which we have to guess the intended meaning.

Comment: @farerobe, the first regex matches `nameFunction('otherFunction.get('''+string_variable+''')')` just fine. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rH2mD2).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't allow the closing bracket in the functions params.

```
\w+\(.*\)
```

this would do the trick.

Comment: `.*` is greedy, so this wouldn't work because it matches not only the header if multiple headers are present...

Comment: @Michael Krejci your regex does not match correctly multiple functions like `fun1() + fun2()`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to match text before first `(` and all the text between outermost parenthesis then this negative lookahead based regex will work for you:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s*\\((.*?)\\)(?![^)]*\\))");
```

Worked with all 4 of your examples.

#### Online Demo: http://fiddle.re/rmy3a